# Do the job database and the target database need to be sitting on different servers?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-logic-apps, job-scheduling

I am following the official Azure documentation to create an Elastic Job Agent so that I can run some heavier queries on Logic App.

In [the section where one should create credentials for running jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-jobs-overview#credentials-for-running-jobs), one thing got confusing for me. Do the job database and the target database need to be sitting on different servers? I know that the database dedicated to jobs should be clean and empty, but the diagram implies somehow that the two are residing on different servers or maybe I am mistaken.

[image: Create the job credentials - MS Azure Docs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for Martin Cairney's answer and add to his answer.

**For Example:**
There are 3 User DBs on my server.
[image]

1. I will use one of the User DB named `josephsql3` as Job Agent database.
   Following is my sql script to create an **Elastic Job group** on my server.

```sql
EXEC jobs.sp_add_jobstep @job_name='CreateTableTest',
@command=N'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE object_id = object_id(''Test''))
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]([TestId] [int] NOT NULL);',
@credential_name='jobuser',
@target_group_name='DemoGroup'
```

2. The job is trying to build a table on the target DBs. By default, the `josephsql` and `josephsql2` and `josephsql3` will be the target db because they are on the same server, but my target db is `josephsql2`. So I need to exclude `josephsql` and `josephsql3` by the following script

```sql
EXEC [jobs].sp_add_target_group_member
@target_group_name = N'DemoGroup',
@membership_type = N'Exclude',
@target_type = N'SqlDatabase',
@server_name = N'<server-name>.database.windows.net',
@database_name =N'josephsql'
GO

EXEC [jobs].sp_add_target_group_member
@target_group_name = N'DemoGroup',
@membership_type = N'Exclude',
@target_type = N'SqlDatabase',
@server_name = N'<server-name>.database.windows.net',
@database_name =N'josephsql3'
GO
```

3. We also can add other server to the **Elastic Job group** we created previously. The premise is that we need to create the same credential on another server. Then we can use the following script to add another server.

```sql
EXEC jobs.sp_add_target_group_member 'DemoGroup',
@target_type = 'SqlServer',
@refresh_credential_name='masteruser', 
@server_name='<other-server>.database.windows.net'
GO
```

4. When we `exec jobs.sp_start_job 'Job_Name';`, then we can use `SELECT * FROM jobs.job_executions WHERE is_active = 1 ORDER BY start_time DESC`  (Execute this query multiple times)to monitor the execution. We can see the job will be executed on both servers

[image]

Comment: Under Martin's answer, I asked "So there is no need for creating a new server just for the JobDatabase.", to which you answered, "Yes, it is." But in your own answer, all 3 databases are sitting on the same server. In Step 3, you state that "We also can add other server to the Elastic Job group we created previously." There is a difference between "there is a need" and "can". Could you please be a bit more clear?

Comment: 1, There is no need for creating a new server just for the JobDatabase. 2, I'm mean we can create a new database not a server. 3, The experiment is also to prove Elastic Job also can perform tasks across servers.

Comment: The extra database for jobs does not seem to be included in the free one-year plan that my client has. So, unfortunately, I could not test your solution. Do you know If there is an alternative?

Comment: In your case, you can add Elastic Job Agent to your single DB. If the computing power is not enough, you can expand the database pricing tier.

Comment: To make things totally clear - Joseph means that you CAN create another Database on the SAME logical server if you so choose.    However the Elastic Job Agent has the flexibility to target one or more logical servers (including all the databases located there) with the same job.

Answer (score 3):

In the graphic, the "Job DB" is the database that is created to support the Elastic Job Agent.

The "Target master db" and the "Target user db" are the databases that you want to execute the job against.

The reason that there is a "master" and a "user" db is so that the Elastic Job Agent can perform tasks such as get the names of all databases on that logical server when you select the server as the target.

The format shown where you have a LOGIN 'jobuser' is again a simplification - if you want to run the same Job query against multiple databases then this saves creating the USER WITH PASSWORD or AAD USER in each database - create it once in master and then map a USER to that LOGIN.

The 'masteruser' is only used to refresh metadata about what databases exist on that server.

Once you create the 'masteruser' and the 'jobuser' at the target you can then create the CREDENTIALS back on the Job Agent database so that the Job Agent can connect to the target as the LOGINS that were defined.   The IDENTITY must match the LOGIN on the target and the corresponding SECRET must match the corresponding PASSWORD on the target.

Depending upon where you place your target databases, it is entirely possible that the Job Agent database AND your target database could be on the same server - however they do not HAVE to be on the same server.

Comment: Thank you! So there is no need for creating a new server just for the JobDatabase.

Comment: @disasterkid Yes, it is.

Comment: @JosephXu Now I am confused. Martin's answer states that "Depending upon where you place your target databases, it is entirely possible that the Job Agent database AND your target database could be on the same server - however they do not HAVE to be on the same server." Could you elaborate?

Comment: Ok, @disasterkid , I will use an example to illustrate.

Comment: Due to budget limits, for now, we only can afford one database in our Azure subscription. When I tried to add a new database for jobs, even the most basic database seems to cost. But just curious. Can the jobdb be inside master so we have only 2 databases? Probably not since I could not assign the master to the Elastic Job Agent. But just curious.

Comment: In Azure SQL DB - conceptually the master database is more of a logical container than a true database. You cannot create objects in master other than Principals.

I'm surprised at the budget restrictions - the running cost for the minimum recommended Job Agent database can be as low as US$14.73 per month.  I'd be very shocked if that blew a budget!!!

Comment: Your answer was also correct. But I chose Joseph's only because it also contained the code. Thank you so much nonetheless.